# Session Id generation by third party to call apex

Tags: apex, webservices, soap, wsdl, session-id

I’ve developed a webservice which basically allows third party to update field Processed_status__c on opportunity object. I’ve generated opportunityUpdate.wsdl file which I would share with them.

However I’ve a question in my mind, In order to access this service, they would need to generate sessionId and then they would pass sessionId in session Header. For this I would need to generate Partner wsdl and share with them. This partner wsdl have lot of service in them.

May I know if there is any better way to share only login functionality and opportunity Update facility keeping in mind that system only supports SOAP service.

Comment: You can compose your own WSDL referencing only those SF operations that are needed, including login. It would be quite tedious but technically possible.

Comment: @identigral I've personally whittled down such an API, it really isn't too hard if you understand the format and have reasonable tools to work with. I forget the details now, but I used some Java-based tool back in the day to just delete the entries I didn't need, it worked out pretty well.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yup, we've done it in a text editor.

Comment: @identigral, sfdcfox, Thanks for you the answer. I would try to compose new wsdl. I tried to look for the tool but I wasn’t able to find any.